# Magento after upgrading from 1.6 to 1.9,Google analytics report shows zero visitors

Tags: php, google-analytics

i had updated my website from magento 1.6 to 1.9,and when i checked the google analytics report of our website for this month , it is showing 0 visitors.How could be it happen, did  i need to change any thing in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Google Account Number is in `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Google API` and `Enable` is set to "Yes"

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer,i had set Enable to yes,will it take google to analyze long time